# Integral of Infinite Division

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

In my Calculus II class this question was posed. It is a definite integral, but the function integrated is infinitely dividing. I tried $u$ substitution, but cannot find the correct term to use as my $u$.

$$
  \int\limits_0^6 \frac{xdx}{1-\frac{x}{1-\frac{x}{1-\frac{x}{\quad\ddots}}}}
$$

Any help? Thanks so much!

Comment: Are you sure about that upper limit of the integral?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $y$ be the continued fraction.  Then

$$y = \frac{x}{1-y}$$

or

$$ y^2-y + x=0$$

which means that

$$y = \frac12 \pm \frac12 \sqrt{1-x}$$

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

$$\text{If }\frac{x }{1-\frac{x}{1-\frac{x}{1-\ldots}}}=y,$$

$$ \frac x{1-y}=y\implies y=\cdots$$